# Using a list as a key to match to another

Tags: python

I have 4 lists and I need to match them using the first two as a key:

```
keyNumbers = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
keyLetters = ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
numbers = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
letters = []
```

I want it to work so that letters would be edited for
It should also work with duplicated numbers or letters

Expected Output: E, D, B, C, A

Comment: Actually what is your question? What did you try? You should edit your question depending on these info.

Comment: I didn't understand your Question here. can you show me the expected output you want!

Comment: @Conrad: Please accept the answer which you found useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the indexes

```
>>> keyNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> keyLetters = ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
>>> numbers = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
>>> letters = [keyLetters[keyNumbers.index(i)] for i in numbers]
>>> letters
['C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using all the four lists, you could do:

```
>>> keyNumbers = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
>>> keyLetters = ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
>>> numbers = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
>>> letters = []
>>> temp = dict(zip(keyNumbers,keyLetters))
>>> ','.join([temp[i] for i in numbers])
E, D, B, C, A
```

Comment: Offcourse it is mandatory. Else what is the significance of `keyNumbers` list

Comment: If it is an assignment type question, then it's okay. Unless, `KeyNumbers` is useless and a symbol of poor coding.

Comment: What if keyNumbers isn't [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: Based on name `keyLetters` and `keyNumbers`, I believe `keyNumbers` denotes the number for the alphabet in `keyLetters` at the same index.

Comment: I used your solution but it doesn't work for duplicated values in numbers

Comment: @ConradScherb Can you please show me some `input-output` cases? May be editing your question.

Comment: any solution involving a dict is not an option since duplicate numbers or letters might be given

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, you could always store a list against a dictionary key. So, let's wait until OP posts some critical cases.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it by using `map` function:

```
>>> keyNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> keyLetters = ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
>>> numbers = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
>>> map(lambda x: keyLetters[keyNumbers.index(x)], numbers)
['C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'A']
```

OR, by `list comprehension` as:

```
>>> [ keyLetters[keyNumbers.index(i)] for i in numbers]
['C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'A']
```

Comment: What if keyNumbers isn't sorteed

Comment: @ConradScherb: It will work. Even I don't expect it to be sorted

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
In [1]: zip_list = zip(keyNumbers,keyLetters)
In [2]: [zip_list[i-1][1] for i in numbers]
Out[1]: ['C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'A']
```

Comment: This is pretty short I agree. But what about calling `zip()` in every iteration? Not so good I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ->

```
keyNumbers = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
keyLetters = ['E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
numbers = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]
x=dict()
for i,j in  enumerate(keyNumbers):
    x[j]=keyLetters[i]
y = [x[i] for i in numbers]
print ','.join(y)
```